# How can I change the time I write a comment like Instagram? in reactnative by using dayjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, nodes, dayjs

I am using react native with dayjs.

I want to compare the time when the comment was written with the current time, and then record the compared time on the console.log(expectedtime) by using dayjs

Like this example

```
function displayedAt(createdAt) {
        const milliSeconds = new Date() - createdAt
        const seconds = milliSeconds / 1000
        if (seconds < 60) return `Just before`
        const minutes = seconds / 60
        if (minutes < 60) return `${Math.floor(minutes)}minutes ago`
        const hours = minutes / 60
        if (hours < 24) return `${Math.floor(hours)} hour before`
        const days = hours / 24
        if (days < 7) return `${Math.floor(days)}days ago`
        const weeks = days / 7
        if (weeks < 5) return `${Math.floor(weeks)}weeks ago`
        const months = days / 30
        if (months < 12) return `${Math.floor(months)}months ago`
        const years = days / 365
        return `${Math.floor(years)}year ago`
      }
```

But i want to get time using dayjs

this is my code

```
    import dayjs from 'dayjs' 

    const TodoItem = ({item }) => {

    
    const date = new Date()
    const day = dayjs(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

    console.log("day:",day);

    // day: 2021-04-01 17:46:49

    console.log("item:",item);
 
  
    // item:{

    // PostId: 2
    // ReplyComments: []
    // User: {id: 5, nickname: "일론머스크"}
    // UserId: 5
    // content: "ㅋ"
    // createdAt: "2021-03-29T13:36:35.000Z"
    // id: 273
    // updatedAt: "2021-03-29T13:36:35.000Z"

    // }

    console.log(expectedtime)
```

how can i fix and add my code?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/difference

Comment: than you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .fromNow() method of daysjs.

```
const day = dayjs(date).fromNow();
```